# Difference in response time stats of jmeter aggregate report and jmeter dashboard report

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

In executions when there are errors, I noticed that there is difference in response time table generated by Aggregate Report & Dashboard report in jmeter 3.1.

[image]

[image]

Other than response percentile rest all stats are same.
Is there a issue with jmeter dashboard.